# @bind, @inject and @override

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a beginner of android app developer, and I've seen many open source apps using @bind and @inject and also default @override

I am wondering what are those and what are the differences`@Inject
    LessonCatalogActivityPresenter lessonCatalogActivityPresenter;

```
@Inject
MarketService marketService;

@Inject
ShareService shareService;

@Bind(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;

@Bind(R.id.sliding_tabs)
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Bind(R.id.view_pager)
ViewPager viewPager;

@BindString(R.string.title_activity_lesson_catalog)
String title;

@Bind(R.id.fab)
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson_catalog);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    initToolbar();
    initTabs();
    initTitle();
    lessonCatalogActivityPresenter.setView(this);
    lessonCatalogActivityPresenter.initialize();
}

private void initToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}


private void initTabs() {
    viewPager.setAdapter(new LessonsPageAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(OFF_SCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

private void initTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

@Override
public void injectActivity(ActivityComponent component) {
    component.inject(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;`
```

Comment: `@Override` is referring to 'overriding' a method from a super class, the `@Inject` and `@Bind` look like they are using some sort of Dependency Injection Library like ButterKnife and Dagger.

Answer (score 2):

- the `@Override` annotation indicates that this method exists in one of its super class, see this [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)
- in your example the `@Bind` annotation is used by [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) to map your instance variables viewPager, tabLayout.. to their respective UI components
- and I suppose that the `@Inject` is the one used by [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) to apply dependency injection in your service but we cannot be sure without having a look at the imports at the top of the class